# Why do some pixel values cause stuttering during playback?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, pixel, video-processing

I use the following function to obtain video frames. I either pass `noise_type=None` to obtain original frames or pass `salt and pepper` to and overlay frames with salt and pepper noise (randomly replacing some RGB pixels with (0, 0, 0) or (255, 255, 255) This is passed alongside some probability that a pixel will be replaced with a black or white pixel (e.g. `prob=0.1` to replace 10% of pixels with either a black or white pixel).

Please note, I am using Python 3.7.9 and OpenCV 4.4.0. Also, as the videos are to be ultimately written alongside audio data using moviepy, they are in RGB space; so running this code and viewing the video will be in the wrong colourspace, but you should still see that the video hangs during playback.

```
def get_video_frames(filename, noise_type=None, prob=None):

    all_frames = []
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture()
    if not video_capture.open(filename):
        print('Error: Cannot open video file {}'.format(filename))
        return

    fps = video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    print("fps: {}".format(fps))

    while True:
        has_frames, frame = video_capture.read()
        if not has_frames:
            video_capture.release()
            break
        if noise_type is None:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, dsize=(224, 224))

        elif noise_type == 'salt and pepper':
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, dsize=(224, 224))
            row,col,ch = frame.shape
            s_vs_p = 0.5
        
            salty_x_coords = np.random.choice(frame.shape[0], np.int(np.ceil(frame.shape[0]*frame.shape[1]*prob*s_vs_p)))
            salty_y_coords = np.random.choice(frame.shape[1], np.int(np.ceil(frame.shape[0]*frame.shape[1]*prob*s_vs_p)))
        
            frame[salty_x_coords, salty_y_coords] = 255, 255, 255
        
            peppery_x_coords = np.random.choice(frame.shape[0], np.int(np.ceil(frame.shape[0]*frame.shape[1]*prob*s_vs_p)))
            peppery_y_coords = np.random.choice(frame.shape[1], np.int(np.ceil(frame.shape[0]*frame.shape[1]*prob*s_vs_p)))

            frame[peppery_x_coords, peppery_y_coords] = 0, 0, 0
            
        all_frames.append(frame)
    return all_frames, fps
```

The issue comes with playback, it seems. I generate clean frames and display them using opencv:

```
frames_clean, fps = get_video_frames('C:/some_video_file.mp4')
for f in frames_clean:
    cv2.imshow('clean', f)
    cv2.waitKey(33)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Then I generate noisy frames and display them using opencv:

```
frames_noisy, fps = get_video_frames('C:/some_video_file.mp4', noise_type='salt and pepper', prob=0.1)
for f in frames_noisy:
    cv2.imshow('noisy', f)
    cv2.waitKey(33)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The noisy video hangs/pauses/stutters on some frames. It's really unusual as both `frames_clean` and `frames_noisy` are lists of uint8 frames of the same shape. The only difference is that the noisy frames have some different pixel values. This behaviour is also present if I create a videoclip using moviepy with these frame lists, write them to disk, and play them with VLC/ Windows Media Player. After 2 days of scouring the internet, I can't find any explanation. I would like the noisy videos I generate to play as expected with a seemingly stable display rate as per the clean video without noise. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You don't seem to `resize()` in your last `else:` though you do `resize()` in all other cases? Do you want differently sized frames? You seem to be converting from BGR to RGB for some reason - why? OpenCV likes BGR and expects that when displaying. If you always want to convert colour and resize, you should do it immediately after acquisition rather than repeating the same code in all three `if/else` cases surely?

Comment: Try printing the `dtype` and `shape` of each frame as you append it to the list to see if you are generating odd frames.

Comment: Rather than trying to read a whole video into memory, you could consider using a Python `generator` that yields a frame at a time so as to be far more efficient with RAM.

Comment: @Mark Setchell, thanks for looking at this. The last `else` statement was left in from the original function (I've simplified this to just include what's necessary). I've removed the last `else` statement now, thank you.

Comment: I mentioned in the second paragraph that I ultimately need these frames in RGB space so that I can write to an mp4 file using moviepy. The opencv display window with imshow is purely to demonstrate the problem outside of writing the mp4 file and seeing the same problem during playback. (Also demonstrates that it's not the video encoding etc.)

Comment: I'll try the generator idea, thanks... I was out of ideas at this point! But why do you think this is more memory demanding given that the lists are the same size and the frames have the same datatype? I'm completely confused about the whole thing...

Comment: With a generator you `yield` one frame at a time then carry on in the generator from where you left off the next time you call it so you actually only have 1 frame at a time. So you call the generator as part of the `for` loop.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, why would changing some pixel values cause this to be so demanding in memory? (Assuming that is the problem)

Comment: Also, the generator idea is a good one to see if the problem is holding the entire thing in memory (which it shouldn't be... since the data is of the same shape (30, 244, 244, 3) and type uint8). But ultimately, I'm going to write this to an mp4 file. So I'd like to know what the difference is between the original pixel values and new pixel values such that it's causing these pauses during playback.

Comment: My suggestions were largely based on programming style, efficiency and maintenance so I didn't really expect the problem to be solved... though it often happens that cleaning things up makes problems go away. I can't see the actual issue for the moment.

Comment: I would try commenting out the actual writing of salt and pepper noise next, i.e. the line `frame[salty,salty] =...`

Comment: Absolutely, your comments are helpful. I commented out the frame pixel assignations so it was effectively producing frames without noise, and there is no problem during playback. If I reintroduce either salt or pepper there is a problem. This happens at different salt/ pepper proportions and also if I assign other values like (26, 80, 120) rather than (0, 0, 0) or (255, 255, 255)... I'm out of ideas about what the issue could be :\

Comment: @MarkSetchell May I ask, when you say you can't see the issue; did you run the code and playback was fine?

Comment: I have not run your code as I am on a Mac with different s/w versions and without your input video. I have just been looking at your posted code.